# Excel Gantt diagram -  how do I highlight actual month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, updates, gantt

Let's say I have a Gantt diagram in the following form:

```
   m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9
a1 ||
a2  |||||||
a3        |||||||
a4     |||||
a5 |||||||||||||||
a6            ||||||||||||||
```

and I want to highlight the current month since the project started maybe with thick outside borders and a different backgroundcolor in the header. Is there a way to do it automatically depending on the start date for example?

Comment: Use conditional formating.  Specifics depend on which version of Excel you are using

Comment: I use 2007. So if m1 is current month then highlight it. What about the cells below the date cell? Can I use conditional formatting as well?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:  dates in column headings, use actual start date in first column (say Cell B1), and use formula in cell C1 `=EDATE(B1,1)` and copy accross as may co,umns as required.  EDATE returns a date serial the specified (in this case one) number of months after a given date.

Format these cells with custom code `mmm` (displays three letter month `Jan`, `Feb` etc)

Conditional format on cells in row 1: Format cells that contain: Dates Occuring: This Month

Conditional format for other cells in the month column (example for column B): Use formula: `=MONTH(B$1)=MONTH(NOW())`